# VB form error only when initiated from batch

Tags: vb.net, batch-file

I recently created an application in VB. I would like to initiate this application using a batch file. I have successfully done this (...initiate from batch file...) with other programs. However, I just recently ran into a weird issue I can't resolve....

First, and most importantly, **the application I created works!!** If I manually initiate the .exe file, it does everything it should be doing.

However, when I open the exact same .exe file using a batch command, I get an unhandled exception error--it takes issue when I probe the size of an array using the .length() function. Importantly, the batch is trying to open the .exe file, because I wouldn't be getting an error if it wasn't doing so.

For those curious, the batch command I am using is:
*START C:"\FolderPath\Application.exe"*

I guess I'm just perplexed by the fact that it works fine when I manually initiate the .exe, but it generates an error when I try initiating the .exe from bat. I'm thinking that the batch command I'm using is doing something more than just opening the .exe?

Does anyone have any ideas?

Any help/advice is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is the batch file in the same folder as the .exe?  Are you starting it using a shortcut?  Can you provide more details about the error?

Comment: Batch is in a different location as the .exe. And I am not running a shortcut. 

Good news, and thank you for this idea, when I move it into the same folder, it does work!!! 

The batch I am creating is supposed to work in a larger automated system, so *not* having it in the same folder would be preferable, however I probably can make it work if there's no other option.

Comment: 1) error message, 2) code.

Comment: Did you try with START /D C:\FolderPath C:\FolderPath\Application.exe?

Comment: In your batch file, try changing the current directory to the folder where the app is located.  i. e. add a line before the start:  `cd C:"\FolderPath\"` and see if that helps.

Comment: @RBarryYoung The error message is an unhandled exception.. "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." When I look into the details, the error appears to be stemming from the following line in my code: *Dim GetSizeOfArray as Integer = SubjectCounterArray.Length()*

Comment: @ChrisDunaway That solved the issue, thank you so much for your help! It is greatly appreciated!!